# The create new table option does not show up in the data

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I created a new Data Base, but when I want to create a new table I can only see "Refresh" or "Proprieties", no Add New Table. There were a few people with the same problem asking for help, I've tried to do what they did and still no success. One of the options was to open the Command Prompt and create a new one using the command C:\sqllocalbd create "Instance". But it did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Is this within Visual Studio Sql Server Object Explorer or Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: It's Visual Studio Sql Server Object Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a new database in the object explorer window, you can expand the database to see the tables tab which, if you've just created the new database will only show system tables. If you right click on the tables folder icon you can hit add new table from there.

[image]

Alternately, at the top of the object explorer window there's an icon with a star that will allow you to run database queries. You can use t-sql to create tables from there

[image]

Comment: It sill does not appear, I've tested the connection and it succeded. I just can't see the Add New Table when I right click the Tables.

Comment: Are you able to do it via the t-sql method?

Answer (score 3):

As Microsoft says in its preconditions:

" Ensure that you have SQL Server Data Tools installed. On the View menu, you should see SQL Server Object Explorer. If it's not there, go to Add or Remove Programs, click Visual Studio 20XX, select Change, and select the box next to SQL Server Data Tools. "

I had the same issue.